# How convert HTML web site template to ASP MVC website

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have downloaded a HTML website template, and i want to use that template to use my MVC project, can anyone to help me?

How can i add HTML website to ASP.net MVC project (html to chtml)

Comment: HTML is already valid inside a `cshtml` file. You can paste HTML source into it and it'll work.

Comment: i'll check, thank you Rowan Freeman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the template's html in _Layout page which works as a master page for mvc.

For content part(which will change for every page) use @RenderBody() in Layout page and use content part html on every view.

Please add Layout page _Layout.cshtml for every view.